# Django 'TestMiddleware' object has no attribute 'get_response'

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with my django TestMiddleware code
My djando version 
Django     3.0.6

My code 
middleware.py

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
class TestMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    '''中间键类'''

    def __init__(self, request):
        '''服务器重启之后，接受第一个请求时调用'''
        print('--init--')

    def process_request(self, request):
        '''产生request对象后，url匹配之前调用'''
        print('--process_request--')

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, *view_args, **view_kwargs):
        '''url匹配之后，视图函数调用之前'''
        print('--process_view--')

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        '''视图函数调用之后，内容返回浏览器之前'''
        print('--process_response')
        return response
```

setting.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    # 'booktest.middleware.BlockedIPSMiddleWare',
    'booktest.middleware.TestMiddleware',
]
```

Error

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 03, 2020 - 13:38:28
Django version 3.0.6, using settings 'test5.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
--init--
--process_request--
Session data corrupted
Internal Server Error: /index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/coco/.virtualenvs/bj19_py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/coco/.virtualenvs/bj19_py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
AttributeError: 'TestMiddleware' object has no attribute 'get_response'
```

I am new for python , pls I need some help

Comment: Remove the `__init__` method. The `MiddlewareMixin` provides `__init__` for you.

Comment: Note that the `MiddlewareMixin` is designed to make it easy to write middleware that works with old-style middleware (Django < 1.10) and newer versions. If you're not trying to support old versions of Django, you don't need `MiddlewareMixin`. See the docs on [writing your own middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) for how to write a simple middleware class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying to implement middlewares the old style by using the `django.utils.deprecation.MiddlewareMixin` mixin.

Newer versions of middlewares need different methods.
Please refer to the official documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/

It will now look like:

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.
        print('--process_request--')

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.
        print('--process_response')

        return response

    def process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        print('--process_view')
```

you could add additional methods like `process_exception()` `process_template_response()`

If you really insist on using the deprecation middleware mixin (which I would definitely not do for any new code)

Then you can try:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
class TestMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    '''中间键类'''

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''服务器重启之后，接受第一个请求时调用'''
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print('--init--')

    def process_request(self, request):
        '''产生request对象后，url匹配之前调用'''
        print('--process_request--')

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, *view_args, **view_kwargs):
        '''url匹配之后，视图函数调用之前'''
        print('--process_view--')

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        '''视图函数调用之后，内容返回浏览器之前'''
        print('--process_response')
        return response
```

Comment: messages crossed. I added a comment about how to use with the MiddlewareMixin.

But I would really try to avoid using this old style way of middlewares. It's less efficient and really only intended to use with old middlewares. 
The idea is you copy the source of the old middleware and *just* add the mixin.

Comment: After append super().__init__(*args,**kwrgs).Able to print --init--. Tks